# ORMDroid won't open sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying use ORMDroid to store some data in an application.

When I try and store something, I get this logcat:

```
01-20 17:42:28.130  19691-20215/me.kennydude.wallet E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) cannot open file at line 30199 of [00bb9c9ce4]
01-20 17:42:28.130  19691-20215/me.kennydude.wallet E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) os_unix.c:30199: (2) open(//kennydude_wallet.db) -
01-20 17:42:28.130  19691-20215/me.kennydude.wallet E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Failed to open database 'kennydude_wallet.db'.
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:669)
        at com.roscopeco.ormdroid.ORMDroidApplication.getDatabase(ORMDroidApplication.java:132)
        at com.roscopeco.ormdroid.ORMDroidApplication.getDefaultDatabase(ORMDroidApplication.java:91)
        at com.roscopeco.ormdroid.Entity.save(Entity.java:720)
        at me.kennydude.wallet.ActivityEditCard$1.run(ActivityEditCard.java:91)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I've followed everything the ORMDroid guide told me to do, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong at the moment :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the same thing.  It's because it tries to open it normally first, which fails, prints this error, and is caught.  It is then opened or created, which passes, so there's actually nothing to worry about.

Comment: I noticed this actually. It just looked more severe :/